# Run C++ program from terminal. Get output in same terminal window

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

When I run my c++ programs from Terminal (Mac OS X), output from programs is shown in a new Terminal window.

What can I do to prevent the new window, and just have the programs' output straight in the window thats already open?

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you run your programs?

Comment: In Terminal I write

open test

to run the program called test that does cout << "Hello world!"

A new window pops up with the text

Last login: Fri Apr 27 18:28:13 on ttys000
Markuss-MacBook-Pro:~ markushatg$ /Users/markushatg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bhtggxbgtoncfebbdzicrsuvtifh/Build/Products/Debug/test ; exit;
Hello, World!
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: It would be great if it would just write Hello world! in the already open window and nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

I believe gcc comes with the XCode tools package.

If you have gcc installed, open terminal window, cd to the directory where you put your cpp file, and type:

```sh
g++ myTestFile.cpp -o main; ./main
```

Replace 'myTestFile' by the name of your file, naturally. you can also rename the 'main' which  is just the name of the compiled module, which you need to run by typing ./main to retrieve the output of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the `open` command.

```
$ open foo
```

This will open a new terminal window.

Don't use the `open` command if you want the program to run in the current terminal window.<sup>†</sup>

```
$ foo
```

---

<sup>† You should obviously leave out the dollar sign.</sup>

Comment: Just typing in the name of the executable doesn't show me any generated output.

Comment: Nothing. Just a new line with name of the folder i'm in and my username

Comment: What's the source code of your program? Post it [here](http://pastebin.com) if it's longer than one line.

Comment: Reading between the lines, the name of your executable is "test". Running "test" from the terminal will probably be executing /bin/test, not ./test. Try running "./test" to force execution of the local file.